# How do I click a javascript button with htmlunit?

Tags: java, javascript, htmlunit

I'm working on an application that will automatically click a button on a webpage using htmlunit in Java. Only problem is that that button is a javascript button, so the standard getInputByName() won't work. Any suggestions with dealing with this? The code for the button is included below.

```
<a class="vote_1" id="1537385" href="/javascript%3Avoid%280%29/index"><img src="/images/parts/btn-vote.gif" alt="Btn-vote" /></a>
```

In addition, here's the other code for voting.

```
<div id="content"><script type="text/javascript" src="/js/scriptFeeds/voteArticle.js"></script>
```

Which leads to the following javascript:

```
var pressed = new Array();

$j(document).ready(function() {
var nr = $j("input#number_of_articles").val();
for(var i=1; i<=nr; i++){
    $j("a.vote_"+i).click(function(){
        var article   = $j(this).attr("id");
        $j('#'+article).hide();
        if (!pressed[article]) {
            pressed[article] = "yes";
            jQuery.post('/vote-article', {
                _token: $j("#_token").val(),
                article_id: article
            },function(data) {
                $j("span.numberOfVotes_"+data.id).html(data.votes);
            }, "json");
        }
        return false;
    });
}
});
```

Comment: I'm aware, was going to use java with htmlunit.

Answer (score 12):

Try using this addOn for firefox, it records your actions and generates the HTMLUnit code for the same. may be it could help.
http://code.google.com/p/htmlunitscripter/

Comment: thanks for mentioning htmlunitscripter.  It helped me with my [screenscraping question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704209/downloading-morningstar-webpages-for-screenscraping/).

Answer (score 9):

There's nothing special about clickable images.   Something like this should work:

```
button = page.getHtmlElementById( "1537385" ) ;
page = button.click() ;
```

HtmlUnit will then run the Javascript and return the updated page.

If the id attribute of the 'a' tag isn't constant, you may need to use XPath to grab it.

Answer (score 5):

I have a very similar link on one of my pages. If you can call .click() on any HtmlElement, it should be able to run associated Javascript. Here is my code (generated from HtmlUnitScripter):

```
HtmlElement element4 = null;
Iterable<HtmlElement> iterable5 = page.getAllHtmlChildElements();
Iterator<HtmlElement> i6 = iterable5.iterator();
while(i6.hasNext())
{
    HtmlElement anElement = i6.next();
    if(anElement instanceof HtmlImage)
    {
        HtmlImage input = (HtmlImage) anElement;
        String[] elements = "http://example.com/pages/powerbutton.png".split( "/" );

        if(input.getSrcAttribute().indexOf(elements[elements.length-1] )> -1 )
        {
            element4 = input;
            break;
        }
    }
}

HtmlPage page = element4.click();
```

Comment: thanks for creating htmlunitscripter.  It helped me with my [screenscraping question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704209/downloading-morningstar-webpages-for-screenscraping/).