# Crawler4j and Tripadvisor

Tags: javascript, crawler4j

I'm writing a crawler for Tripadvisor, using crawler4j. I need to collect all the reviews for an item, but the links to the "next" reviews (those with numbers) have associated not a link, but a javascript function. This function is defined somewhere in Tripadvisor's servers. Is there a way to evaluate these functions and get the page which they return?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [eval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp)?
or [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call) if you need to change the caller context.

eval takes a string as an input and tries to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTMLUnit to get page content. This library can be used to run all javascript codes and then get page code to manipulate.

Here is an example [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897871/how-do-i-click-a-javascript-button-with-htmlunit), taken from a question on stackoverflow.

```
    HtmlElement element4 = null;
Iterable<HtmlElement> iterable5 = page.getAllHtmlChildElements();
Iterator<HtmlElement> i6 = iterable5.iterator();
while(i6.hasNext() {
    HtmlElement anElement = i6.next();
        if(anElement instanceof HtmlImage) {
        HtmlImage input = (HtmlImage) anElement;
        String[] elements = "http://example.com/pages/powerbutton.png".split( "/" );

        if(input.getSrcAttribute().indexOf(elements[elements.length-1] )> -1 ){
            element4 = input;
            break;
        }
    }
} 
HtmlPage page = element4.click();
```