# Obtaining download URL with Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I am writing a Java program which connects to this [site](http://www.youtube-mp3.org/), and then simulates passing a URL into the textfield, hitting the convert button, and then obtaining the generated download URL. I inspected the sites network traffic and the download's URL has the following data under the headers tab:

**After pressing the download button I see...**

```
**General:**
Remote Address:64.233.171.121:80
Request URL:http://www.youtube-mp3.org/a/itemInfo/?video_id=KMU0tzLwhbE&ac=www&t=grp&r=1439422557443&s=63079
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
**Response Headers:**
view source
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:249
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 12 Aug 2015 23:35:57 GMT
Server:Google Frontend
Vary:Accept-Encoding
**Request Headers:**
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Location:*
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:_ga=GA1.2.1715601918.1425946204; ux=cce7b6d7-c6b9-11e4-8ef7- 5557045ab030|0|0|1439422547|1439854547|3536a31fad07ba73ecc1e4ba4b3cf3d6; __  utmt=1; __utma=120311424.1715601918.1425946204.1439420885.1439421591.16; __utmb=120311424.3.10.1439421591; __utmc=120311424; __utmz=120311424.1439421591.16.16.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided)
Host:www.youtube-mp3.org
Referer:http://www.youtube-mp3.org/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4)    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36
**Query String Parameters:**
view source
view URL encoded
video_id:KMU0tzLwhbE
ac:www
t:grp
r:1439422557443
s:63079
```

And under the "Response" tab in inspect element (under Network) it shows:

```
info = {"status": "serving", "h2": "c0c0d91ef9ca62df13a43f71c6ad8ea3", "image": "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/KMU0tzLwhbE/default.jpg", "progress_speed": "", "ads": "", "title": "Developers", "h": "fa5ef79cbdee0bb33da3348818b26715", "px": "", "ts_create": "1439422557", "length": "3", "r": "NzMuMjE1LjIxMC4w", "pf": "", "progress": ""};
```

Now, I am trying to obtain this data which I will then parse into a download URL after taking the necessary parameters. However, I am not sure how to access this information. I created a Jsoup GET request like this:

```
Connection.Response res = null;
    Document doc = null;
    String id;
    String vidID;
    String downloadURL;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("URL: ");
    id = input.nextLine();
    vidID = id.substring(id.length()-11,id.length());

    try{

        res = Jsoup.connect("http://www.youtube-mp3.org/")
                .referrer("http://www.youtube-mp3.org/")
                .header("Accept","*/*")
                .data("video_id",vidID)
                .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                .execute();
      //not sure how to proceed
}
```

But that is not working out for me. I am able to get the necessary video_id paramter from the user's input so that is fine. However, I am unable to find the rest of the necessary parameters listed for the "Request URL:" param. How can I construct a request to connect to the site and pass my inputted URL? And then after doing so, how would I obtain the information listed under the Network/Reponse tab in inspect element?

Thanks for any advice

> EDIT:

So the request URL looks something like this: (Note: This is the request leading up to the page with the download URL info under the Response tab, so I first need to do a request to the following URL)

```
http://www.youtube-mp3.org/a/itemInfo/?video_id=KMU0tzLwhbE&ac=www&t=grp&r=1439422557443&s=63079
```

I know the video_id, I'm assuming the "ac" value is always www and that the "t" value is grp, however, the "r" and "s" parameters seems to be generated differently for each video, and I am not yet able to see how...

**UPDATE:** Alright so after further probing, it looks like I need to do two things to accomplish what I need...

1. Make a GET Request to a URL in the form of the following:

   http://www.youtube-mp3.org/a/itemInfo/?video_id=KMU0tzLwhbE&ac=www&t=grp&r=1439425642030&s=5534

while passing in values for "item" (no problem), "el" (no problem), "bf" (no problem), "r" (need to get), and "s" (need to get).

> Then after doing this...

2. Make another GET Request to the pre-download URL which is in the following form:

   http://www.youtube-mp3.org/a/itemInfo/?video_id=KMU0tzLwhbE&ac=www&t=grp&r=1439425642030&s=5534

while passing in values for while passing in values for "video_id" (no problem), "ac" (no problem), "t" (no problem), "r" (need to get), and "s" (need to get).

and then

3. Obtain Response data and construct download URL

Comment: The `r` parameter appears to be the current time since epoch in milliseconds.

Comment: @Vulcan hmm didn't think of that. Is there a way I could obtain this value and then pass it in the URL?

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis()` returns time since epoch in milliseconds.

Comment: Regarding your question as a whole, however, it may be worthwhile to approach this differently and simulate clicking the "Convert video" button using [HtmlUnit](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3897871/1247781) and then scraping the resulting HTML for the download link.  That way, you won't need to worry about any back-end information required by the webpage, as you could simply simulate how a human user would use that web interface.

Comment: @Vulcan The problem is, I am planning on eventually adding this to an android app which does not support HtmlUnit unfortunately. I've been looking for alternative dynamic web parsers but I can't find for android

Comment: @Vulcan do you know of any libraries which could work for this purpose?